SideTitles is not recognized while adding latest version dependency fl_charts: 0.69.0
I am trying to implement line chart in my project, for this i am using fl_charts.
Main problem is SideTitles is not recognized (comes red line).
SideTitles not recognized X-axis title

Y-axis title error

I import the latest package of fl_charts i.e., 0.69.0, also if i use some older version like 0.30.0 there flutter was not able to recognize AxisTitles.
Main goal is to achieve this UI

Here i need to add scroll also horizontally but only graph  and Y -axis months should scroll not X axis line.

It would seem to be in most recent fl_chart releases: https://pub.dev/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/SideTitles-class.html

so what should do now, any other libraries or method if you suggest ...
